# SQLITE3: Creating database from command line takes forever

Tags: sql, linux, sqlite

I run a service that creates many SQLITE3 databases and later on removes them again, they live for about a day maybe. They all have the same schema and start empty.

I use this to create a new blank SQLITE3 database:

```
sqlite3 newDatabase.db < myschema.sql
```

The myschema.sql file contains three table schemas or so, nothing fancy, no data. When I execute the above command on my rather fast, dedicated linux server, it takes up to 5 minutes to complete. There's processes running in the background, like a couple of PHP scripts using CPU time, but everything else is fast, like other commands or inserting data into the DB later on. It's just the creation that takes forever.

This is so weird, I have absolutely no idea what's wrong here. So my only resort right now is to create a blank.db once, and just make a fresh copy from that rather than importing from a SQL schema.

Any idea what I messed up? I initially thought the noatime settings on linux were messing with it, but no, disabling didn't change anything.

Willing to provide any configuration/data you need.

**Edit:**

```
This is what strace hangs at:
12:29:45.460852 fcntl(3, F_SETLK, {type=F_WRLCK, whence=SEEK_SET, start=1073741824, len=1}) = 0
12:29:45.460965 fcntl(3, F_SETLK, {type=F_WRLCK, whence=SEEK_SET, start=1073741826, len=510}) = 0
12:29:45.461079 lseek(4, 512, SEEK_SET) = 512
12:29:45.461550 read(4, "", 8)          = 0
12:29:45.462639 fdatasync(4
```

Comment: Can you paste a few lines more after it hangs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possibility is to use the `strace` command to see what's happens :

```
strace -f -s 1000 -tt sqlite3 newDatabase.db < myschema.sql
```

If it hangs somewhere, you will see.

Is your schema is HUGE ?

**NOTE**

- in case of questioning about too high `I/O` disk, try the command `iotop -oPa`, you will see "who's" put the mess in your system

Comment: Just trying this out. Figured I needed to apt-get strace first. Then I discovered, it also seems to hang there at some point (last line has been paused for over 2 minutes, then it said unpacking..) `The following NEW packages will be installed:
  strace
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 140 kB of archives.
After this operation, 406 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://ftp.hosteurope.de/mirror/ftp.debian.org/debian/ squeeze/main strace amd64 4.5.20-2 [140 kB]
Fetched 140 kB in 0s (871 kB/s)`

Comment: Is `df -h` report a 100% full disk ?

Comment: no, df-h tells me I use 0% to 1% of all disk space. it must have gotten something to do with the disk. I am still in the `unpacking strace` stage, which should not take longer than a second or two...

Comment: I've accepted your answer since it provides everything anyone else might need to fix a similar problem. thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Alright I think I figured out the issue.

The server was running a couple of PHP scripts in the background that seemed to somewhat behave with CPU load, it often spiked at 100%, but all other commands worked fine mostly except installing things through APT-GET and installing new SQLITE3 databases out of a schema.

What probably caused the problem was the heavy disk access (IO operations). I re-installed APC, upgraded to a new version, figured out it was disabled for CLI (which is a default) but enabled it since I have long-running scripts, also added a few usleep(100) here and there.

I stopped every single PHP command, basically killed every program not required. Checked system usage through MYSQL Workbench, it seemed still very high until I realized that this is an average value. If you wait another 10 minutes, it will average out, which in my case was close to 0% LOAD. Perfect.

Then I restarted the scripts and it seems to be holding things down now.

I tried the SQLITE3 command mentioned above and it worked instantly, as expected.

So, simple cause: Not only high CPU load, but also HEAVY IO, disk access.